# Gmail API Java Quick Start Program: How to Enter the Authorization Code in Eclipse

Tags: java, gmail-api

I am using `Eclipse` to run the `Gmail API` Java Quick Start program. (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-java).

I've been able to get the `authorization code`.  However, I can't find a way to communicate it to the program.

It seems to expect it this code via command line data entry.  However, I don't know any way to do that in Eclipse.

As an alternative, I put the authorization code directly into program.  Like this:

```
//System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type"
//                  + " the authorization code:\n" + url);

// Read code entered by user.
// BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String code = "valueOfTheAuthorizationCode";
```

But this gives me the error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException:     400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Judy

Comment: There are 2 common problems that cause invalid_grant errors: 1. Your server's clock is out of sync with NTP 2. You've exceeded the refresh token limit. If you're using a single refresh token to generate access tokens frequently, then this could be the root of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clue @SGC.  Turns out the authorization code had timed out.  Not sure if it's ok to add that much of my confusion came from using the Gmail API Quick Start Program to try and figure out OAuth authorization for an offline program.  I have since discovered this very helpful link https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/blob/master/examples/dfa_axis/src/main/java/dfa/axis/auth/GetRefreshToken.java